# JQuery AJAX won't work without nested DIV, why?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Imagine the following index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="MY_FORM" action="./index.php" method="get">
        <input name="var_name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 

    <!-- <div> -->
    <div id="MY_CONTENT">
        <?php
            var_dump( $_GET ); 
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#MY_FORM').submit(function()
        {
            var form = $(this);
            $.get('./', form.serialize(), function(data)
            {
                var updated = $('#MY_CONTENT', data);
                $('#MY_CONTENT').replaceWith(updated);
            });
            return false;
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is a simple AJAX form. When this form is submited then MY_CONTENT should be refreshed with AJAX (hence form's action="./index.php").
Question:
I found the code working only when MY_CONTENT div is enclosed in the another div.

I placed the

```
<!-- <div> -->
<!-- </div> -->
```

around MY_CONTENT. this must be changed to div to get the script working.
Why does MY_CONTENT have to be wrapped in a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `data` contains all elements that were children of the head and body tags, but not the head/body itself. you can get rid of the wrapper by using

```
var updated = $(data).filter("#MY_CONTENT")
```

instead since it is a direct child of the body tag after you get rid of the wrapper.

Another solution (as pointed out by Fabrício Matté) is to only return the target html if the request is an ajax request.

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && Strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    var_dump( $_GET );
}
else {
   ... rest of your page ...
```

then you can just do

```
$('#MY_CONTENT').html(data);
```

Comment: Yes, or you can just echo the markup that should come inside the content div and apply `.html()` directly to it.

Comment: Of course, it'd require sending an extra param through Ajax to differentiate an ajax submit from a regular load, +1 for the coherent answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté unless you check the headers, :)

Comment: Oh yes, almost forgot about the `X-Requested-With` header that jQuery automatically sets, thanks for the remainder. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var updated = $('#MY_CONTENT', data);
$('#MY_CONTENT').replaceWith(updated);
```

by:

```
$('#MY_CONTENT').html(data);
```